# Array destruction and unused vars marked by eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, destruction

I have code like this in my code:

```
let [a, b, c, d, e] = await component.getState.call(game.gameId);
```

Variables `b`, `c`, `e` used below in code but not `a` and `d`. In the same time I have eslint check that marks unused variables.

Is there any way to write destruction more correct to resolve this issue? I know about `esling-disable-line no-unused` but prefer to avoid it.

Comment: You can just omit non-used variables, `let [, b, c, , e] = `

Comment: @ASDFGerte just noted that you already commented much before, please add this as answer :)

Comment: @ASDFGerte you are fantastic!

Comment: @kiddorails Should a question's answer boil down to a very short fact, a comment may come close to it already. I rarely post answers these days, unless the situation explicitly demands it. This is because answers imply completeness, require longer flavor-text, and potential follow-ups. Also rep doesn't concern me much. I potentially may not have time or motivation for follow-ups, and could not answer details about ESlint, as I have very little experience with it (likely less than OP - here, a javascript syntax detail just happened to be relevant). That you post it as answer is completely fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace it with empty placeholders:

```
let [, b, c, , e] = await component.getState.call(game.gameId);
```